# Traversing an ftp folder with python

Tags: python, ftp, download, directory, traversal

I need to write a python script that traverses a folder on a FTP server.

## for file in ftpfolder:

```
#get it
#do something untoward with it
```

Snippets and non-wheel-reinvention advice welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[ftputil](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftputil/2.4.2) is the third-party module you're looking for:

> ftputil is a high-level FTP client
>   library for the Python programming
>   language. ftputil implements a virtual
>   file system for accessing FTP servers,
>   that is, it can generate file-like
>   objects for remote files. The library
>   supports many functions similar to
>   those in the os, os.path and shutil
>   modules.

Note for example the snippet [here](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac):

```
# download some files from the login directory
host = ftputil.FTPHost('ftp.domain.com', 'user', 'secret')
names = host.listdir(host.curdir)
for name in names:
    if host.path.isfile(name):
        host.download(name, name, 'b')        # remote, local, binary mode
```

`ftputil` is pure Python, very stable, and very popular on `pypi` (users rate it 9, which I think is the maximum on pypi's scale).  What's not to like?-)

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking for something similar since ever!

Comment: @Alex, would have been nice if you mentioned why use `ftputil` instead of stdlib's `ftplib` (EG, ease-of-use).

Comment: @Tshepang, I quoted the part about it being **high-level**, a **virtual filesystem**, and generating **file-like objects for remote files** -- these, of course, are the core characteristics that make it attractive. Whether one sees this attractiveness as focused on ease-of-use, sheer power, or conciseness, seems totally secondary to me -- and since my answers tend, if anything, to be overly long (unless I pay special care), I typically try to avoid considerations and observations that strike me as "totally secondary".

Comment: @Alex, In understand your point, but my main concern is that your answer makes it look like ftplib doesn't even exist, because you don't even mention it.

A mention does't need to be longer than "stdlib has ftplib but rather use ftputil because it's high-level... blah..."